# Como pegar as imagens que estão retornando e transformar numa galeria?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, lightbox

Estou usando uma mistura de plugin do WordPress com código PHP para conseguir executar uma tarefa que é juntar todas as imagens de um determinado post em uma galeria.

Gostaria, nesse código abaixo, de saber como eu poderia jogar todas as imagens retornadas numa galeria e mostrar uma após outra.

```
if( class_exists('Dynamic_Featured_Image') ) {

    $featured_images = $dynamic_featured_image->get_featured_images();

    foreach ($featured_images as $f_images) {

        $thumb = str_replace('150x150', '328x400', $f_images['thumb']);
        $real = $f_images['full'];

        echo "<a href=".$real." rel='lightbox'>";
            echo "<img src=".$thumb." rel='lightbox' />";
        echo "</a>";
    }
}
```

O `$featured_images` retorna um array de imagens com dois tipos de imagens que eu renomeia cada tipo como `$thumb` e `$real`. O thumb mostra ela pequena o real mostra ela em uma lightbox no tamanho real.

> **[image: O que eu queria é como colocá-las dentro de um mesma slideshow??]**

O que está acontecendo atualmente é que, como o link e a imagem estão dentro do foreach, cada volta do foreach, ele cria uma nova lightbox e o que eu queria era juntar tudo numa galeria só.

Comment: Mas como que seria "juntar tudo numa galeria só" ?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se eu entendi seu problema, pois sua pergunta ficou um pouco confusa
Mas dê uma olhada na documentação do plugin que esta usando o lightbox.
Dependendo de qual esteja usando, um simples `rel='lightbox[galeria]'` resolve.